# Java Retrieve the actual value of the public key from the KeyPair object

Tags: java, cryptography, key

I wanted to ask how to retrieve the actual values of the private and public keys from the KeyPair object because i need to export them and save in a database.

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

System.out.println("Public key " + keyPair.getPublic());
System.out.println("Private key " + keyPair.getPrivate());
```

The output is:

```
Public key Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 105712092415375085805423498639048173422142354311030811647243014925610093650322108853068042919471115278002432342007597147610508132502035047888382465733153739247741208519707861808073276783311634229563965825609200080862631487160732889423591650215084096832366499080850540875321197564283324922935557797293830551071
  public exponent: 65537
Private key sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@35e71
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use `keypair.getPublic.getEncoded()` or `keypair.getPrivate.getEncoded()`:

RSA private keys are encoded in PKCS#8 format, and public keys are encoded in X.509 format.

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey prv = keyPair.getPrivate();

byte[] pubBytes = pub.getEncoded();
byte[] prvBytes = prv.getEncoded();

// now save pubBytes or prvBytes

// to recover the key
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey prv_recovered = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvBytes));
PublicKey pub_recovered = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubBytes));

System.out.println("Private Key: \n" + prv_recovered.toString());
System.out.println("Public Key: \n" + pub_recovered.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply downcast to `RSAPrivateKey` and `RSAPublicKey`. Once you've done that you can access the methods of these classes.

```
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic());
BigInteger modulus = pubKey.getModulus();
```

etc.

Comment: This shows how to get the individual elements that the question showed in te printout of the key. For storage, look [to the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886537/589259). Private keys should however generally be stored in a `KeyStore`, rather than as plaintext value on disk or a DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the docs?

Try the following :

[getModulus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAKey.html#getModulus%28%29)

[getPublicExponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html#getPublicExponent%28%29)

[getPrivateExponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey.html#getPrivateExponent%28%29)

They all return [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

than can in turn be stored.

Also see if the [raw encoded format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29) is of help.

Comment: This answer shows the methods, but it completely skips how to get to the RSA classes, and it doesn't specify the format "raw encoded format" - the documentation talks about **primary** encoding format, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the code from original question, here is the solution to print out the content of the RSA Key itself:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

System.out.println("Public key " + keyPair.getPublic());
System.out.println("Private key " + keyPair.getPrivate());

//to print actual content

Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

System.out.println("Private key content: " + encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
System.out.println("Public key content: " + encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
```

Hopefully this helps more digital army in em war! Peace :D