# How to extract modulus and private exponent from a private key in java?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

Is there a way to extract **modulus** and **private exponent** from a **encoded** RSA private key?

I know how to do it with `openSSL` but I'm looking for how to do it in **Java**. I can't find how ?

I'm able to retrieve the `RSAPrivateKey` from the ans encoded one but I can't find how to get the modulus and the private exponent.

Comment: Why not use [`getModulus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAKey.html#getModulus--) and [`getPrivateExponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey.html#getPrivateExponent--) ?

Comment: Actually I have PrivateKey not RSAPrivateKey and it does not provide those two methods

Comment: You don't show any code, but you should be able to just cast `PrivateKey` to `RSAPrivateKey` since unless you're doing something strange your PrivateKey *is* an RSAPrivateKey.

Comment: Ahh it worked, I didn't know I could cast it. Thank you ;) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Retrieve the actual value of the public key from the KeyPair object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19819805/608639)