# Java RSA Key Sizes

Tags: java, rsa

I am trying to learn how to sign messages using the RSA algorithm with SHA256 in Java. When I generated a 2048-bit KeyPair, I found that both the public and private key were 294 bytes. Here is my code for finding the size of the keys:

```
import java.security.*;

public class RSATesting
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();

        byte[] publicKeyBytes=pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        System.out.println(publicKeyBytes.length);
        byte[] privateKeyBytes=pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        System.out.println(privateKeyBytes.length);
    }
}
```

Why are the keys not 256 bytes?

Thanks

Comment: Your private key is only the same size as the public because you called `getPublic` for both of them :)

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921508/trying-to-understand-java-rsa-key-size (mostly) from nearly 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA keys aren't like AES keys.

AES keys are some random bytes. RSA keys are numbers. The RSA modulus (`N`) defines the lenght.

Your key is 294 bytes long, because of `getEncoded();`. It returns a formatted key and not the real lenght.

Comment: Does this mean that the getEncoded() returns the bytes of a number?

Comment: Yes. You can just print pair.getPublic(). It will print numbers.

Comment: How can I find the modulus N?

Comment: @PeterY. Try System.out.println(pair.getPublic()); It will show your modulus.

Comment: There is a little more to an RSA public key, namely the public exponent.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Yes. And there is also a private exponent

Comment: @Jakob how can I find the private exponent? `System.out.println(pair.getPrivate());` just gives `sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@ffeec6fe`

Comment: @PeterY. This post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818550/java-retrieve-the-actual-value-of-the-public-key-from-the-keypair-object

Comment: @PeterYe: answering your question - no, it will not. getPublic().getModulus() and so on will get you the numbers themselves, if that is what you are looking for,

Answer (score 0):

You are asking not for the key, but for an encoded representation of it. That's why it is named `getEncoded()`.

Standard encoding for all crypto stuff is ASN.1 DER, and according to the specific standards for RSA keys, there's version, algorithm identifier, and the key integer itself to be present in the encoding.

Your question is similar to asking "when I store a picture in a GIF, why is the size not the number of pixels multiplied with byte per pixel?".
Encoding is more complex than just the raw data.

Adding a quote on details, to make this answer more useful:

```
    PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
      version Version,
      algorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
      PrivateKey  BIT STRING
    }
    
    AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
      algorithm   OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
      parameters  ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL
    }
```

with AlgorithmIdentifier for RSA being the OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 in OID format.

See also Java JDK docs, e.g. [Key interface JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html).